# How to proof $(x^n)' = nx^{n-1} (with \enspace n \in \mathbb{R})$?

Tags: derivatives, real-numbers, square-numbers

It's trivial to proove that :

$$(x^n)' = nx^{n-1} \enspace (with \enspace n \in \mathbb{N}) .$$

But how to proove it with $n \in \mathbb{R}$ ?

Because it works.

Example :

$(x^{\frac{1}{2}}) = \frac{1}{2}x^{-\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$

...etc.

Thank you for this help.

Comment: How do you define $x^n$ with $n \in \Bbb R$? If you defined it as $e^{n\ln x}$, then the proof follows from $(e^y)'=e^y$, $(\ln x)' = 1/x$, and then Chain Rule.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the problem of even defining $x^n$ for $n\in\Bbb R$ is already hard. Typically we define it first for $n$ a positive integer, then $n\in\Bbb Z$, then $n\in\Bbb Q$. But there isn't an obvious definition for something like $x^\pi$. You can either define $x^\pi=e^{\pi \ln x}$ or you can hope that $\lim\limits_{c\to \pi,c\in\Bbb Q},x^c$ exists. Both work, but the first one is more workable, so thats usually the fastest way to define all exponentiation. From there you can use the chain rule.

Comment: Thank you @azif00

I think it answers the question.

Comment: Can you make an answer for all, to validate it as answered ?